# How to work with locators in ArcGIS 10.0

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, geocoding

I wrote my locator class which grab features from my web service. I picked it up in the ArcMap and now I can perform a search in the geocoding toolbar.
The suprise for me is the way results of gocoding are showed: green point for the first feature which has been found. How can I see information about found features? Where can I find other features? Where is the database used by locator?
I can't find decent documentation about these issues. I use ArcGIS 10.0.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what your goal is? And what steps you've done. Id on't know what you mean by "locator class". What does "picked it up in ArcMap" mean? Your custom Locator class (button?) or a Locator in a Geodatabase?

Comment: Can you offer a snippet of your code on how you did this as I am very interested what arcObjects interfaces you had to implement to create you custom geocoding .

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what your goal is. The place to start on how to create your own Locator is to from [resources.arcgis.com](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/geocoding/10.0/locators). This should describe how you take data in your geodatabase and basically create the data structures to perform [geocoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding).

If you already have a Locator that you want to use (either provided online from arcgis.com or something you've created in a geodatabase with the above steps), you can use the ArcObjects API to retrieve results from the locator. Depending on which method you use, you can retrieve multiple results.

See [Closest Intersection Sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/000100000227000000.htm) and [Find an Address Sample](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000000vs000000.htm).

Comment: thank you for the response, but I more or less sorted it out) I found GP tools which use locators. I developed my own COM class which implements necessary arcObjects interfaces and provides geocoding and reverse geocoding.